# jQuery/JavaScript error

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#shortly').countdown({until: 12, 
    onExpiry: liftOff, onTick: watchCountdown});
});

$('#shortlyStart').click(function() {
    shortly = new Date();
    shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 12.5);
    $('#shortly').countdown('change', {until: shortly});
});

function liftOff() {
    alert('We have lift off!');
}

function watchCountdown(periods) {
    $('#monitor').text('Just ' + periods[5] + ' minutes and ' +
        periods[6] + ' seconds to go');
}
</script>

<span id="shortly"></span>
<button name="newPageStart" id="shortlyStart" type="button">Start</button>
<span id="monitor"></span>
```

Comment: Seems to be working according to the specifications.

Comment: when i click the start button the timer couldn't be restart.,i mean again it should goes to 00:00:12.,(It's not working for me when i click the button)

Comment: @john2103 - Your question has *zero* letters that describe what should happen, and what actually happen. You can't just paste the code and expect people to know what's the problem (though I've guessed). Try editing the question and its title and give some more details.

Comment: My Problem is when i'm click the start button the timer will not go to 00:00:12.,it's a bidding process...my timer is decreasing when the actual time 00:00:12 to 00:00:00..,when the user enter in to the bidding process they hit the bid button (i,e)start button.,when decreasing the time.,for exampl.,you are enter into my website hit the bid button (i.e) start button when the timer running with the time of 00:00:08.,after that it should goes to 00:00:12 not a 00:00:07...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$('#shortlyStart').click` event should be bound in the `$(document).ready` event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#shortly').countdown({until: 12, 
    onExpiry: liftOff, onTick: watchCountdown});

    $('#shortlyStart').click(function() {
        shortly = new Date();
        shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 12.5);
        $('#shortly').countdown('change', {until: shortly});
    });
});
```

The line `$('#shortlyStart')` is looking for the `<button>` with `id=shortlyStart`. However, when that line of code runs, the button isn't likely to have been created yet, and the click event isn't bound to any element. Place it in the `$(document).ready` event (which is the same as the first line: `$(function() {})`, it's a shortcut), and the line would run *after the whole document was loaded*.

See also: [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Reference link.,
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Click the callbacks menu.,

I want the exact functionality of the first example of this site...
"Action it in 5 seconds:"